# Rails4 validation order; return 'can't be blank' instead of invalid format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I set up the validator for `uuid`.

in `app/model/user.rb`

```
  VALID_UUID_REGEX = /\A[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}\z/i
  validates :uuid, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: VALID_UUID_REGEX, message: 'invalid uuid format' }
```

and it works. However when I insert some uuid with invalid format, it returns `uuid: can't be blank` error, instead of `invalid uuid format`.

Any ideas? Maybe some validation orders?
( I use almost the same validator for `email`, and it works.)

**UPDATE**
I also tried separate validation, but the result is the same.

```
  validates :uuid, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  VALID_UUID_REGEX = /\A[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}\z/i
  validates :uuid, format: { with: VALID_UUID_REGEX, message: 'invalid uuid format' }
```

Comment: you're already validating against a regex.. is `presence: true` required in your validation ?

Comment: yes, that is true. but why it works for email, but not uuid?

Comment: The message suggests that uuid never reaches the controller. Have you added uuid in the permitted  params in users controllers?

Comment: oh. yes I do. params.require(:user_info).permit(:uuid, :name, :email)

Comment: Try to remove 'presence: true', send and invalid format and see if format validation  actually returns the error message.

Comment: yeah it does. it returns the error message.

Comment: i guess you got it working

Comment: the validation is being used by you is right. Can u give me an example for which its not working

Comment: Why are you letting users change their uuid?

Comment: @max I've been developing another subsystem. When users try to register , we need to check if it's valid format. Changing uuid is not happened.

Comment: @Toshi Did you try separate validations?

Comment: @DaniilMaksimov Yes I did. I updated my question.

Comment: Maybe you have method `uuid` and it overrides attribute.